# Where to store reverse authorization logic in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture

"Straight" resource authorization is pretty simple and clear in Laravel. You need to create a policy, implement a method in it, register the policy and check an authorization using the `User::can` method:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Checks whether a user can view a post
     */
    public function view(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->author_id || $user->group_id === $post->group_id;
    }
}

if (!$user->can('view', $post)) {
    abort(403);
}
```

But what about "reverse" authorization? Saying "reverse authorization" I mean getting the resources which a user is authorized to. As for the example above, it is getting the posts which a user can view:

```
function getPostsUserCanView(User $user)
{
    return Post::where('author_id', $user->id)->orWhere('group_id', $user->group_id)->get();
}

$posts = getPostsUserCanView($user);
```

What is the proper or the best place to put the logic of the `getPostsUserCanView` function in a Laravel application? How do you solve this problem in your application?

Answer (score 2):

For that you can use [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) directly.

In your `Post` model:

```
...
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post', 'employee_id','user_id');
    }
...
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
public function getPostsUserCanView()
{
    $posts = auth()->user()->posts;
    return $posts;
}
```

The `auth()->user()` gives you the logged in user, then the `posts` method (that defines the relationship between `User` and `Post` models) will collect all the posts that has the `$author_id` equals to the `$primaryKey` (in my example the `user_id`) of the `user`.

---

## Where to put the logic

If it's a small app you could store that logic directly in a controller, but if you want to decouple more the code you could do something like this:

1 - **A user repository**: where all the interaction with the database is made. Basicly CRUD functions. This isolate the driver used by the app to persist the data.
2 - **A user service**: where all the actions related to the user are made. This class can call the repository to modify the data but also can use other functions like managing relationships and others. This avoids controllers to interact with models.
3 - **A user controller**: A controller is basicly the glue of the app, this calls methods of different services (of models) to interact with each other.

This way your classes has only one purpose. As the SOLID states.

Comment: The question is «where to store the `getPostsUserCanView` function», not «how to implement the `getPostsUserCanView` function». And the answer code returns all the posts made by a user (which is not the full authorization logic of the question example).

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part. I will update my answer.

Comment: What about putting the authorization logic to a policy like this: `class PostPolicy { ... public static function getPostsUserCanView(User $user) { ... } }`? This approach keeps all the post authorization logic in a single place.

Comment: Or like this: `class PostPolicy { 
... public static function viewFilter(User $user) { return function ($query) { $query->where('author_id', $user->id)->orWhere('group_id', $user->group_id); } } }` and use this way: `$posts = Post::where(PostPolicy::viewFilter($user))->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get()`. This code formatted: https://pastebin.com/nWS9LneM

Comment: Yeah, the auth logic surround `posts` can be managed in a `Policy` class. If the app is small you could do it in a `Request` class directly (in the `authorize()` method).

Comment: My app is pretty big with a complex authorization logic so I want to keep it all in one place not to mess